# resources for understanding deviance

Tags: references, deviance

Can you please recommend a book or another resource for learning more about deviance, at roughly undergraduate level?

I'm aware there are many specific questions and answers about deviance on this site but I wish to find a longer and broader reference that develops the general theory.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Chapter 2 in the book
McCullagh, Peter; Nelder, John (1989). Generalized Linear Models, Second Edition.
is a good read and addresses deviance adequately.